# What Perl variables are used for the positions of the start and end of last successful regex match?

Tags: regex, perl, perlvar

What Perl variables are used for the positions of the start and end of last successful regex match?

Comment: Let me look that up in the manual for you...

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: This is the first couple of pages of _Mastering Perl_ :)

Comment: It's not like I don't know what's in the manual. Why do you think I tagged it perlvar? And even knew about its existence. I had just forgotten. I am a C programmer, not Perl. Geez guys this site really is lame. Unless I am talking about some arcane thing people downvote...

Comment: If you can't run 'man' on Unix when you forget things, then you should probably choose a nick other than 'unixman'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the `perlvar` man-page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) explains:

> `$+[0]` is the offset into the string of the end of the entire [last successful] match. This is the same value as what the `pos` function returns when called on the variable that was matched against.
>
> `$-[0]` is the offset of the start of the last successful match.